# Double vertical scroll bar on overflow-x:hidden

Tags: html, css

After a lot of searching, I came to question this. Due to very large code, it was becoming headache to identify which part of the page was causing overflow. I then used:

```
html, body{

   overflow-x:hidden;
   height:100%;

 }
```

I used another alternative way, which was to create a wrapper div outiside the body tag and then applied the overflow-x:hidden property to it but none of these seem to fix this 'double vertical scroll bar issue'.

Comment: I don't get why `overflow-x:hidden` would fix a double VERTICAL scrollbar issue

Comment: try to remove height: 100%

Comment: You should have used overflow-y:hidden instead

Comment: @Danield It doesn't fix, it adds this issue

Comment: @ARJUN well considering your page is large and you can't just do overflow-y:hidden, it would just make the page static on a specific position

Comment: Then that would be specific problem, try to provide code where exactly you need static or no need of overflow.

Comment: @ARJUN Arjun, the page has a lot of content, so vertical scroll is normal, for instance, i have created multiple containers for education, work experience, comments etc. So for this, there will be a normal vertical scroll. In this case, if i use overflow-y:hidden` then I will not be able to scroll the page normally. I hope you get the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, not using the html tag and using just the body solved my problem

```
body{
overflow-x:hidden;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hey I think the solution, if you are still looking for it, is

```css
  html, body{
    
     overflow-x: hidden;
     max-width: 100%; 
     height: auto;
    
}
```

instead of writing height:100% that you have specified.
Hope this helps!